# How to see Spark UI in AWS Glue4.0

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

Is there any way we can edit any parameter to see bigger logs files for spark UI in AWS Glue. I am using Glue4.0 and able to see the UI when log files are of smaller size.

```
The error message I am getting is.
The max filesize is 512 MB. This Spark UI log file is 619.31 MB.
```

Comment: Can you add the full error stack trace you're getting?